# Input values and 'Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts ' Error

Tags: matlab, input

I'm a Matlab newbie and i'm doing a homework for a structural analysis class in which i need to input the coordinates for the joints(node) of various structural members. So i made this code.

```
%% Coordinates for Structure Nodes
Nnodes=input('Enter structure nodes\n');

Coords=zeros(Nnodes,3);

  for  i = 1:Nnodes
    Coords(i,1)= i;
    Coords(i,2)= input(['x coordinate of node', num2str(i),' = '],'s');
    Coords(i,3)= input(['y coordinate of node', num2str(i),' = '],'s');
  end

  fprintf('These are the structure coordinates\n');
  Coords
```

This code works when i type in coordinates in x and y that range from 0 to 9, however once i enter a coordinate >= 10 it displays this error

```
Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts"*.

The problem is that you are using strings here. Any value more than 9 or less than 0 will give you error.
For example, consider string `'18'`. Now `'18'` is actually `'1'` at a separate index and `'8'` at a separate index for strings but you are trying to save them at one index i.e. at `(i,2)` and `(i,3)`.

The solution is to not use them as strings. Modified working code is:

```
Nnodes=input('Enter structure nodes\n');
Coords=zeros(Nnodes,3);
for  i = 1:Nnodes
    Coords(i,1)= i;
    Coords(i,2)= input(['x coordinate of node', num2str(i),' = ']);
    Coords(i,3)= input(['y coordinate of node', num2str(i),' = ']);
end
fprintf('These are the structure coordinates\n');
Coords
```